# plotly+dash: Is it possible to use partial property updates with dash-daq components?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a `dash_daq.Indicator` for which I want to do a partial property update in a callback. Is this possible? The indicator object has a `to_plotly_json()` method, where I tried to make the update happen, but this did not work.

Can partial property updates not be used with dash-daq components?